# PhpStorm - Refactoring can not be performed

Tags: phpstorm

I am getting the following member while attempting to use the: `Refactor->Pull Members Up` option in PhpStorm.

> Refactoring cannot be performed File <...>
>   /PhpStorm.app/Contents/plugins/php/lib/php.jar!/com/jetbrains/php/lang/psi/stubs/data/_types.php
>   is located in a read-only container.

Now the error is telling me that "the container" is read only, and should be set to "read write".

I am not 100% sure what is means by "the container"...

I have checked the actual PhpStorm.app as well as the php.jar files and they are both Read/Write...

Any help appreciated...

Comment: Why are you trying to refactor **PHP stub files** ??? Show screenshots/code that you are trying to refactor.

Comment: Well, the "pull members up" option is a lazy way of taking a method from a class and pulling it to the classes interface. Right click on the method, -> refactor -> pull member up... done.

Comment: My main question/concern was -- why are you trying to do this on classes from stub files (standard libraries) and not your own classes? The way how "Pull Members Up" works (in simple words) is that it moves methods from class class into another .. and I see no reason why would you want to *remove* (lets say) `modify` method out of PHP's standard `DateTime` class...